# IE 8 clipping google marker icons

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer, google-maps-styling

Hi I have seen a similar problem to my own elsewhere but the answers offered haven't worked for me. Basically the map I've created works fine in all browsers I tested except IE, the bespoke icons called via the:

```
google.maps.MarkerImage("mapIcons/"+ iconColor +".png",
```

are 26 by 34 and this size is set too.

I read that linking to a stable version of the API may help but this hasn't resolved the issue
I also tried:

```
    <!--[if IE]>
  <style>
    div#map img{
      margin-top: -1px;
      margin-left: -1px;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

This too failed, the page in question can be viewed here:
http://nuweb.northumbria.ac.uk/google/ourframe.html

Comment: [This thread in the Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/2de0ea37567063d8) and its associated issues in the issues list may be relevant.